# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props._navigate.replace/push')

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and trying ( followed a tutorial ) to move to another screen when a button is clicked, this is the updated code I have and a photo of the error I get when pressing the button.
index.ios.js:

```
export default class Application extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator){
    if(route.name == 'login'){
      return <Login navigator={navigator}/>
    }else if(route.name == 'home'){
      return <Home navigator={navigator}/>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Navigator
      initialRoute={{name: 'login'}}
      renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}/>
  }
}
```

LoginForm:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.navigate = this.navigate.bind(this);
    }

    navigate(routeName){
        this.props.navigator.replace({
            name: routeName,
            Component: Home
        });
    }
    render(){ 
        return(
            <View style={mStyle.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle='light-content'/>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={mStyle.btnText}>
                        LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.navigate('home')}>
                    <Text style={mStyle.noLoginTxt}>
                        CONTINUE WITHOUT LOGIN
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to move from login screen to home screen when button is clicked.
I get this problem when pressing the button on the emulator:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of how you use `Navigator` ?

Comment: I just started with React Native, So I did what he did here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7u5wBQB-vg

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems that you are facing.

1.- The syntax is:

```
this.props.navigator.{any_method}
```

Such as:

- `this.props.navigator.push`
- `this.props.navigator.replace`

Not

```
this.props._navigate.{any_method}
```

2.- If you have child views make sure you are sending to the childs the `Navigator` property such as.

```
<View>
  <MyChildComponent navigator={this.props.navigator} />
</View>
```

3.- Make sure your child view gets the props from the parent on the constructor.

Change

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this._navigate = this._navigate.bind(this);
}
```

To

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    // The following line is not required since you are using an arrow function to call this one. 
    // this._navigate = this._navigate.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still got the same problem.

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the view that renders the view you have on your question so we can see with more detail the problem. Thank you.

Comment: done. I learned it from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7u5wBQB-vg I just started learning React Native.

Comment: I did an update to my answer let me know if you have questions or if you still have issues..

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same problem. this is so weird, seems pretty simple in the tutorial lol.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a mismatch between property you use in `Navigator` and in your component

Change

```
_navigate(name){
        this.props._navigate.replace({ //I also tried push, same problem.
            name
        });
 }
```

to

```
_navigate(name){
        this.props.navigator.replace({ //I also tried push, same problem.
            name
        });
}
```

Comment: I tired, it is like that now but still the same problem.

Comment: Can you post the error with above code. Unless you are doing something different in navigator, this should work.

Comment: Also make sure you do props.navigator and not props.navigate

Comment: I edited the OP with the updated code I have now and a photo of the error I get in the emulator. Thanks :) .

Comment: Its strange this doesn't work. Before you call your replace method, can you add console.log(this.props) and console.log(this.props.navigator).

Comment: Where can I see the log? I'm using VS Code and can't see it anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141446/discussion-between-coder-hacker-and-john-doe).